# Active Directory: pinpoint cause for access denied when modifying objects

Tags: active-directory, permissions, access-control-list, windows-server-2019, organizational-unit

I need a general way to determine the cause of access denied errors when modifying/moving/etc. objects in AD. I know that I can view "effective permissions" but not sure which permission corresponds to which real world action.

For example, the computer objects in a certain OU have the Delete effective permission, but I can't move it to a new OU that was created.

Answer (score 1):

You probably haven't unchecked `Protect from accedental delition` option in that OU.

Comment: Can't I without touching that, move items out of that OU? The individual computer objects don't have accidental deletion turned on

Comment: Are you member of domain admins?

Comment: No, I'm not a domain admin. But I figured out the problem. I'm not the owner of the computer objects.